# Getting all groups when using pd.Grouper in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe like that:

```
zone  date         a    b
AL   2014-01-31   8.88  3286.6
AL   2014-01-31   0.61  1047.105
BS   2014-01-27   1.59  145.283
RF   2014-01-31   2.67  2842.35
RF   2014-01-31   3.4   0.26
```

I want to group by month and zone

```
df.iloc[:, 1] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 1])

g = df.groupby(['zone', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])
```

If I use `pd.Grouper` there's just one zone

```
>>> g.groups.keys()
dict_keys([('AL', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00'))])
```

If I don't use `pd.Grouper` all the zones are there:

```
g = df.groupby('zone')

>>>> g.groups.keys()
dict_keys(['AL', 'BS', 'RF'])
```

I would like to get all the zones grouped by month so that the result would be something like:

```
>>>> g.groups.keys()
dict_keys([('AL', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00')), 
           ('BS', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00')), 
           ('RF', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00'))])
```

It's my very first question in here so if I can make it better please tell me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me, because if I print out `ngroups`, it says 3:

```
g = df.groupby(['zone', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')])
g.ngroups
3
```

Furthermore, I get all the group keys if I iterate over `g`:

```
[k for k, _ in g]    
[
 ('AL', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M')),
 ('BS', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M')),
 ('RF', Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M'))
]
```

Another solution that works nicely for me is `g.indices`:

```
g.indices

{('AL', numpy.datetime64('2014-01-31T00:00:00.000000000')): array([0, 1]),
 ('BS', numpy.datetime64('2014-01-31T00:00:00.000000000')): array([2]),
 ('RF', numpy.datetime64('2014-01-31T00:00:00.000000000')): array([3, 4])}
```